# Change delimiter in a csv from ; to ,

Tags: powershell

I cannot seem to change the delimiter in a .csv from `;` to `,`.

The issue is that one of our overseas customers have a default delimiter of `;` because of regional settings, but our system requires the `,` separator.

I cannot use the `-replace` because there are semicolons in some string entries that need to be kept there.

Here are the options I have tried:

```
Import-Csv -path $home\ | Export-Csv C:\Users\Dean\Desktop\test.csv -useculture

Import-Csv -path $home | Export-Csv C:\Users\Dean\Desktop\test\test.csv -Delimiter ","

Import-Csv -path $home | Export-Csv C:\Users\Dean\Desktop\test.csv -Replace "^\"|\"$", ""
```

I have also tried

```
Import-Csv -UseCulture | ConvertTo-Csv | Out-File and Import-Csv -Delimiter | ConvertTo-Csv | Out-File
```

None of these options are throwing out errors but the delimiter is still `;` when checking the csv again. The only time I have seen these args work are if I export or outfile a csv to a location without the `-delimiter` or `-useculture` arg.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creating a csv using ; as the delimiter:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\ | Select-Object FullName, Name, LastWriteTime |Export-Csv c:\temp\test.csv -Delimiter ';' -notypeinformation
```

Sample of the csv:

```
"FullName";"Name";"LastWriteTime"
"C:\APP-V_Global";"APP-V_Global";"8/5/2013 12:45:04 PM"
"C:\Program Files";"Program Files";"10/4/2017 7:48:06 AM"
"C:\Program Files (x86)";"Program Files (x86)";"10/10/2017 1:44:51 PM"
"C:\Temp";"Temp";"12/5/2017 1:29:34 PM"
"C:\Users";"Users";"9/6/2017 8:30:00 AM"
"C:\Windows";"Windows";"11/17/2017 4:16:43 PM"
```

Import the csv telling powershell what the delimiter is:

```
$imported = Import-Csv c:\temp\test.csv -Delimiter ';'
```

Sample output:

```
$imported
FullName                             Name                                 LastWriteTime
--------                             ----                                 -------------
C:\APP-V_Global                      APP-V_Global                         8/5/2013 12:45:04 PM
C:\Program Files                     Program Files                        10/4/2017 7:48:06 AM
C:\Program Files (x86)               Program Files (x86)                  10/10/2017 1:44:51 PM
C:\Temp                              Temp                                 12/5/2017 1:29:34 PM
C:\Users                             Users                                9/6/2017 8:30:00 AM
C:\Windows                           Windows                              11/17/2017 4:16:43 PM
```

Export the information back out:

```
$imported | Export-Csv C:\temp\test.csv -delimiter ',' -notypeinformation
```

File Contains:

```
"FullName","Name","LastWriteTime"
"C:\APP-V_Global","APP-V_Global","8/5/2013 12:45:04 PM"
"C:\Program Files","Program Files","10/4/2017 7:48:06 AM"
"C:\Program Files (x86)","Program Files (x86)","10/10/2017 1:44:51 PM"
"C:\Temp","Temp","12/5/2017 1:29:34 PM"
"C:\Users","Users","9/6/2017 8:30:00 AM"
"C:\Windows","Windows","11/17/2017 4:16:43 PM"
```

The basic process works so I'm wondering if your input files are the issue. If this isn't working please considering sanitizing and posting a sample csv.

Comment: Thank you for the response Stephen. I was thinking maybe it had something to do with the input files too but I have had the same issue on my machine at home with basic tests such as exporting a list of running processes to the desktop and changing the delimiter on those. One thing I haven't tried yet is telling Powershell what the delimiter is during Import-csv before I pipe through to either ConvertTo or Export. If that doesn't work I will upload the csv

Comment: Ok, so this is working as expected now. I'm not sure what the issue was before as the only thing I have done differently is '$imported =' and inserting '-delimiter' in both the import and export but the original script on the server is run via task scheduler and I was just editing that originally so i'll remove any tasks and use job triggers to prevent future complications.

Comment: If you are using PowerShell 7 or higher, there is now a -UseQuotes parameter that allows you to get rid of the unnecessary double quotes. See JS2010's comment at:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/f6b610b6-bfb2-4140-9529-e61ad30b8927/how-to-export-csv-without-doublequote